# Prove that if $a<b$, then $-b<-a$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

Prove that if $a<b$, then $-b<-a$

I'm a bit lost in this one, this is what I did:

**First case:** $0<a<b$

$|a|<|b|$, so  $|-a|<|-b|$

Since both are negative and $|-b|$ is greater than $|-a|$, then $-b<-a$

**Second case:** $a<0<b$

Since $a$ is negative, then $-a$ is positive.
Since $b$ is positive, then $-b$ is negative.

So clearly $-b<-a$

**Third case:** $a<b<0$

$|a|>|b|$

$-a$ and $-b$ are positive and $|-a|>|-b|$

So $-b<-a$.

Is this right? It seems clear enough to me, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to prove this.

Comment: Why do you not want to now use $a<b$ implies $a+c<b+c$ for any $c$.  Just repeat this with $c=-b$ and then $c=-a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume: $\exists a, b. a<b \wedge -b\geq-a$

Then: $a-a\le a-b<b-b \implies 0\le a-b<0$ but $a\neq b$ so we have derived a contradiction, hence, $\neg[\exists a, b. a<b \wedge -b\geq-a]$ is true, which implies:

$$\forall a,b. a\geq b \vee-b<-a$$

Thus $a<b \implies -b<-a$ is true when $a<b$ is true.

Comment: But $a<b \implies -b>-a$ when, for example, $a=100$ and $b=1$. You can confirm this by evaluating either side of the implication. I think perhaps you meant to assume something like $\exists a, b. a<b \wedge -b\geq-a$.

Comment: @DavidK...ah, that was sloppy notation on my part. You are correct...I mean $\exists a, b. a<b \wedge -b\geq-a$, like you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In every ordered field 1. if x>0 then -x<0
                       2. if x>0 then y>z ⟹ xy>xz
then x(y-z)>0 implies -(x(y-z))=(-x)(y-z)<0
so that -xy<-xz

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b,c$ be integers.

> **Lemma 2.** $a>b$ if and only if $a-b$ is a positive natural number.
>
> **Lemma 3** *(Addition preserves order).* If $a>b$, then $a+c>b+c$.

You can prove Lemma 3 by Lemma 2.

*Proof.* We have $a<b$. By Lemma 3, adding $-a$ and $-b$, we have, $-b<-a$.

---

Maybe you need consider this definition:

> **Definition 1** *(Ordering of the integers).* Let $n$ and $m$ be integers. We say that $n$ is greater than or equal to $m$, and write $n\ge m$ or $m\le n$, iff we have $n=m+a$ for some whole number $a$. We say that $n$ is strictly greater than $m$, and write $n>m$ or $m<n$, iff $n\ge m$ and $n\ne m$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to assume the addition property of inequality, i.e.,

if $x>y$, then $x+a>y+a$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$?

If yes, then the proof can be made significantly simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in an ordered field $F$, then this is almost a direct consequence of the axiom which states that for all $a,b,c\in F$, if $a<b$, then $a+c<b+c$.

If we assume that $a<b$, then we have
$$
-b=(a-b)-a=a-(b+a)<b-(b+a)=-a
$$
where we add $c=-(b+a)$ to $a$.