# Proof verification for $a > b \implies -a < -b$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I am aware that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116067/prove-that-if-ab-then-b-a) asks  for the verification of a proof of (almost) the same problem but my proof is different and in my opinion, a bit simpler and more intuitive. Here's how it goes :

Let us assume that $a > b$.

We can write this inequality in the form of an equation as follows :
$$a = b + x \text{, where } x > 0$$
On multiplying the *LHS* and *RHS* by $-1$, we obtain :
$$-a = -(b+x) = -b-x \implies -b = -a+x$$
We have already mentioned that $x > 0$. From this, we can say that $-b$ is obtained when we add a positive number ($x$) to $-a$. Hence, $-b > -a \implies -a < -b$

Thanks!

Comment: Simpler and more intuitive is pretty debatable.

Comment: Add $-a-b$ to both sides

Comment: Assuming that "$a>b$" is defined as "$\exists x>0$ s.t. $a=b+x$", the proof looks correct.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's a nice line. That's why I wrote `in my opinion` in the question. What I meant was that since it's comparatively shorter and eliminates the cases, it would be simpler. Isn't that so?

Comment: @Surb Can there be any other definitions of $a > b$? I didn't know that.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu: shorter does not necessarily mean simpler, that depends on the concepts involved. And shorter depends on how you rate the length.

Comment: I get it, that was an illogical thing to say. Hence, debatable too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are allowed to use $a>b\iff a+c>b+c$, then the theorem can be reduced to

$$a>0\iff -a<0,$$ which seems easier.

---

**Update:**

Using the above lemma, you could as well write the whole proof as

"WLOG $b=0$ (translate as required) and $a>0\iff -a<0$".

Comment: Looks like I'm getting some part of it and missing some. Can you please elaborate it's use in the proof.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu: add $-b$ to both sides and rename.

Comment: Do you mean this : $a > b \implies a-b > b-b \implies a-b > 0 \implies -a < -b$? That indeed is a LOT simpler, convenient to understand too.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu: more precisely, $a>b\implies a-b>0\implies b-a<0\implies -a<-b$.

Comment: Even better, thank you!