# Spivak Chapter 1 Question 5, ii

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I know this [exact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116067/prove-that-if-ab-then-b-a) question has been asked, but not yet answered in line with Spivak's answer.

> Prove: If $a<b$ then $-b < -a$

Spivak:

> $b-a$ is in $P$, so $-a -(-b)$ is in $P$

Spivak defines $P$ thus:

> the collection of all positive numbers.

May I call this the "terse" version.

I would like to try a more "verbose" version, with a question.  So, in the vein of Spivak

$ b - a $ is in $P$

$ a - b $ is not in $P$

$ - (a-b)$ is in $P$ $\implies - a + b$ is in $P$ $\implies - a - (-b)$ is in $P$  $\implies -a > -b = -b < -a$

**Question:**
I just wonder if I am taking liberties in the second to third step of the last line? Is this sleight of hand, or a genuine way to obtain the desired result?

Comment: You should include what $P$ is

Comment: @MichaelMorrow done!

Answer (score 1):

Define $a<b$ as $a+c=b$ for some $c>0$.

Then $-a = (-b) +c$ and so $-b<-a$.